# calling an async function from within a timer

Tags: swift, concurrency, timer, task, runloop

I have an async function that has to be called every given time from within a timer.
In order to avoid an Xcode error,

```
func firetimer()  {
      
         let newtimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { newtimer in
            self.myAsyncFunction() // 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(newtimer, forMode: .common)
    }
```

I tried to put it into a task but this gives a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" error while running.

```
func firetimer()  {
      
         let newtimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { newtimer in
             Task{
            await self.myAsyncFunction() // not working
             }
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(newtimer, forMode: .common)
    }
```

In fact I don't need any waiting, the next occurence of the function can be called when the latter is still working.
Any hint on what to do?
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a supporting function:

1. The supporting function is synchronous but calls `myAsyncFunction` asynchronously:

```
func mySyncFunction() {

    // Call the asynchronous function
    Task {
        await self.myAsyncFunction()
    }
}
```

2. Call the supporting function from `fireTimer`

```
func fireTimer()  {
      
         let newTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { newTimer in
            self.mySyncFunction()    // Synchronous
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(newTimer, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, even if the syncFunction only prints something without even calling the async one. There should be a memory problem I don't understand.

Comment: @NightCoder Not every Thread has Runloop, so instead of RunLoop.current try to use RunLoop.main.

Comment: It works great with `RunLoop.current`